# Laravel 5.2 probleme with call mail function

Tags: php, laravel, email, phpmailer

when i try to send email with the mail function il laravel 5.2 a have this error

```
Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver()
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php on line 87 and defined
```

I try several things for adjust my probleme.
Here is my code

-first i try to send mail with de php mail function `mail()`
I know that laravel sends not it's email like this.

and my controller my code loke like this

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Lang;
use Validator;

$data = array(
                'nom' => 'ede',
                'email' => 'rfr',
                'message' => 'cece'
            );

        Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function ($m){
            $m->from('admin@test.com', 'edit');

            $m->to($this->emailContact, 'test')->subject('testt');
        });
```

and my config mail my code like this

```
'driver' => 'emails',
'host' => '',
'port' => 2525,
'encryption' => 'null',
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

I try to delete my chache file and `bootstrap/cache`. I tri to put

`'driver' => 'mail'` in my config file

but in laravel comment a have this

> Supported: "smtp", "emails", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill"

i try to create account to mailtrap et configure smtp with this but a have the seem probleme . I try to delete my .env file. I try change port to 25, 587. I try with my gmail account seem probleme.

In php docs they say to put `sendmail="/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"` and `host="localhost"`  not working

i try this

```
`php artisan config:clear`
`php artisan config:cache`
```